# Were the heavy war reparations on Germany after World War I the main cause of its hyperinflation in 1923?

Tags: germany, economy

World War I victors imposed severe war reparations on Germany. When Germany defaulted, France invaded the Ruhr which was the most heavily industrialized area in Germany to force reparations themselves. If Germany persists in default, it risks further invasion. The easy way out was to print money and inflate the debt away. One can argue that Germany had really no choice but to print money. Because the war reparations were so huge, the money printing was excessive. This created the conditions for hyperinflation to happen later.

Were the heavy war reparations after World War I the main cause of hyperinflation in Germany in 1923?

Comment: Don't have time for a full answer now, but it wasn't only the reparations. Germany had supported all its war effort through loans, and thus the Mark was declining even before the end of the war.

Comment: ["Inflation is always and everywhere a monetary phenomenon in the sense that it is and can be produced only by a more rapid increase in the quantity of money than in output"](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Milton_Friedman) - the choice to print more money may have been constrained by the reparations, and might hvae been further constrained by the fact that Keynes hadn't yet published macroeconomic theory.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The WWI [reparations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_I_reparations) were set in gold marks, and the level of the reparations therefore was actually equivalent to a fixed amount of gold. It wasn't payable in paper marks, the actual currency at the time. It was only payable in currencies that had a fixed exchange rate to gold.

The reason for the hyperinflation is that Germany decided to start [printing money to buy foreign currency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperinflation_in_the_Weimar_Republic) to pay the reparations with. Essentially, they attempted to buy gold from foreign countries with worthless paper and then give the gold back. This, of course, did not work, and only resulted in hyperinflation and a slow-down of the German economy, therefore making it *harder* for them to pay the reparations.

Therefore, it is not the reparations that caused the inflation, but the Wiemar Republic's decision to try and get money for nothing.

Comment: One could argue that had it not been for the heavy reparations, the Weimar republic would not have made the decision to print money to buy foreign currency to pay the reparations. The root cause was still the very heavy war reparations.

Comment: +1, although as Yannis mentioned, the need to repay internal war debt as well was also a factor. About the only way the inflation could have been avoided was to win WWI (or better yet, not start the stupid war in the first place).

Comment: @T.E.D. and Yannis: There were certainly other factors. However, the question centres on whether the severe war reparations was the main cause. After all, other World War I participants also had heavy internal war debts but they did not suffer hyperinflation. It is quite possible that if Germany did not have to carry the extra burden of super heavy war reparations, they might have escaped hyperinflation like the rest.

Comment: @curious Ah, but other countries didn't resort to borrowing (at least not as much as Germany did). France, for example, supported its war effort through taxation (creating war time taxes, etc).

Comment: @T.E.D. I disagree. They could have avoided hyperinflation by not printing enormous amounts of money. That they did so can be attributed to economic ignorance in dealing with the reparations, but the only actually necessary part of that is the economic ignorance. Hence, the reparations was not the cause for the inflation, the cause was the way Germany dealt with the reparations, and tried to cheat them by printing money.

Comment: @LennartRegebro That would have been an option only if not repaying the reparations was an option (which it wasn't. I believe at one point they were late on a payment to France, and France responded by [marching their army into the Ruhr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occupation_of_the_Ruhr).)

Comment: @T.E.D. No, printing money did not help them pay back the reparations. They *thought* it would, because they thought they could get money from nothing by printing money. But it doesn't work that way. What you are claiming now is that Germany essentially was unable to pay the reparations. That's possible but [citation needed]. 1. Note that the occupation of Ruhr happened after the start of the hyper-inflation, and 2. The payments they missed that prompted the invasion was missed payments in coal and lumber, not gold marks.

Comment: @Lennart Regebro : The Ruhr invasion took place in Jan 1923. Wikipedia article put the start of hyperinflation on June 1921. However, the period when inflation went really hyper was in the later part of 1923, as can be seen from the end date of hyperinflation which is January 1924.(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperinflation_in_the_Weimar_Republic)

Comment: @Lennart Regebro : I realized my question is flawed because the reparations were not denominated in paper marks. So, printing money was not a solution anyway. But money printing does help in reducing other debts which were denominated in paper marks. Using paper money to exchange for foreign currencies helped too (at least in the beginning), as you have pointed out. Hyperinflation and Ruhr occupation did help Germany in some ways. It helped Germany gain sympathy among the war creditors and paved the way for debt forgiveness.

Comment: @curious Yes, the Ruhr occupation can very well have been a contributing factor to the inflation. Essentially France walks in and takes resources that Germany otherwise could have sold. That they at that point decide to simply print even more money is perhaps not surprising. But it doesn't change the essential point: The hyperinflation was not caused by the reparations, but it was caused by Germany trying to cheat themselves out of paying them by essentially printing money as fast as they could.

Answer (score 0):

After an all-out war like WWI or WWII, the losing side has nothing to speak of left:  it was "all-out" and they didn't surrender until every resource was found and used.

If, after such a war, there are no reparations, a country may use pretend assets to "pull themselves up by their bootstraps." An example that comes to mind of the bootstrap approach is Germany using pretend assets of the workers' compensation program to back bonds issued for the Autobahn. They existed only on paper, physically, and in peoples' minds since the depression had them on... reduced tax receipts... and there was no physical pile of money any more than the US Social Security program pile of money.

If no reparations, with foreign soldiers coming up and removing whole factories when payments are missed, one can use the not-quite meaningless paper assets to back the money system and keep the hyperinflation spiral from starting and whipping out of control. It also helps if, after a war, the victors take over things for a time and use their own resources to back it, or make implicit promises to the world of such.

But with reparations, the emperor's clothing status is immediately and painfully obvious and everyone begins doing the apparently very human thing of "I gotta get mine while I still can" (and, of course, raising prices and squeezing for payments is also done to make one's own payments and in doing so keep the system fluid and not stuttering to halts so it is admittedly not all selfish). With no gold to put in a bank showroom to let people realize the system is backed (pretend, actually, but you know...), there's mud for everyone's fins.

And then you get hyperinflation. It's not about the reparations themselves, precisely, as in their existence. It is about stripping anything helpful away ('cause you do have your own problems...) and absolutely destroying any pretense that hope exists. Reparations might be required after and several year period of time and actually work. But not probably the "all the money in the world and then some and right this second" kind that they tried then.

Comment: This doesn't really cover the aspect of the weight of reparations, i.e. the potential that lighter reparations (smaller amounts/shorter terms) would have had less of an impact on the German economy. Could also do with some source references for the monetary theory.

Comment: I'd like to see a reference for the assertion in the first paragraph - "they didn't surrender until every resource was found and used". I'm doubtful that Germany exhausted _all_ of its resources in WW1.